# Getting sum of elements of two or more multidimensional arrays with same key in php

Tags: php, arrays, multidimensional-array

I am looking at some functions like `array_merge` and `array_combine` in php.net but I still don't have any idea on how to implement my assumptions of arrays.  My assumption arrays are like below.

```
$data1 = array(
       [0]=>array(
           [2]=>array(
                  [subject1]=>30
                  [subject2]=>50
             )
       )
      [1]=>array(
           [3]=>array(
                  [subject1]=>30
                  [subject2]=>50
             )
       )
    )
$data2 = array(
       [0]=>array(
           [2]=>array(
                  [subject1]=>20
                  [subject2]=>70
             )
       )
      [1]=>array(
           [3]=>array(
                  [subject1]=>30
                  [subject2]=>40
             )
       )
    )
```

How do I get the above 2 (it can be more arrays) arrays into one array like these structure:

```
$datamerge = array(
           [0]=>array(
               [2]=>array(
                      [subject1]=>50
                      [subject2]=>120
                 )
           )
          [1]=>array(
               [3]=>array(
                      [subject1]=>60
                      [subject2]=>90
                 )
           )
        )
```

Please help me. This is my project and it is very important to me.

Comment: @walther, As I mentioned above.I tried array_merge but it justs appends the array at the end of the second array.

Comment: And that's where your own initiative ended? What about manually traversing the arrays and storing the values in temporary variables?

Comment: @walther, thanks for the advice. since I have no idea at all, and I am just a a newbie. please can you help me work out this.

Comment: Do you have any idea what does a recursion or a foreach loop mean?

Comment: Yes I have some like printing `$datamerge` array.

Comment: Good. Then try to use it. You will learn the most if you come up with the solution yourself :) If you have a specific problem with it, then come back here and we can help you further.

Comment: @walther, Please can you at least suggest ways to go.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you are absolutely sure that both arrays have exactly the same nested structure, so that every key at every level exists in both arrays, then you could write this:

```
function array_sum_recursive ($data1, $data2) {
    if (!is_array($data1)) {
        return $data1 + $data2;
    }
    foreach ($data1 as $key => $value) {
        $result[$key] = array_sum_recursive($data1[$key], $data2[$key]); 
    }
    return $result;
}

$result = array_sum_recursive($data1, $data2);
var_export($result);
```

Output with the data you provided would be:

```
array (
  0 => 
  array (
    2 => 
    array (
      'subject1' => 50,
      'subject2' => 120,
    ),
  ),
  1 => 
  array (
    3 => 
    array (
      'subject1' => 60,
      'subject2' => 90,
    ),
  ),
)
```

However, it would be safer to make the function deal with input arrays that might not correspond that well. It makes the function much longer, because of all the tests that have to be done:

```
function array_sum_recursive($data1, $data2) {
    if (!is_array($data1) && !is_array($data2)) {
        return $data1 + $data2;
    }
    // deepest array gets precedence
    if (!is_array($data2)) {
        return $data1;
    }
    if (!is_array($data1)) {
        return $data2;
    }
    $keys = array_unique(array_merge(array_keys($data1), array_keys($data2)));
    foreach ($keys as $key) {
        if (isset($data1[$key]) && isset($data2[$key])) {
            $result[$key] = array_sum_recursive($data1[$key], $data2[$key]); 
        } else if (isset($data1[$key])) {
            $result[$key] = $data1[$key];
        } else {
            $result[$key] = $data2[$key];
        }
    }
    return $result;
}
```

#### More than two arrays

If you need to add more than two arrays like that, you can just progressively sum the next array into the result of the previous sum, like this:

```
$result = array_sum_recursive($data1, $data2);
$result = array_sum_recursive($result, $data3);
$result = array_sum_recursive($result, $data4);
// etc.
```

You could even write a function for that, which takes a variable number of arguments (see [func_get_args()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.func-get-args.php)):

```
function array_sum_recursive_all() {
    $result = array();
    foreach(func_get_args() as $data) {
        $result = array_sum_recursive($result, $data);
    }
    return $result;
}
```

Then you can write:

```
$result = array_sum_recursive_all($data1, $data2, $data3, $data4);
```

Comment: thanks for your answer. Will this method works for more array?

Comment: Can you explain? You mean you want to work with N arrays, and then sum them all together?

Comment: Yes that's what I need. Thanks.

Comment: Added a section to my answer about that.